# Setting up cross account access of IAM user/role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I have a main account user that I want to allow access to a subaccount S3 bucket. I have setup the following stack in my subaccount

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion : '2010-09-09'
Description: 'Skynet stack to allow admin account deploying user to access S3'

Parameters:
  AccountId:
    Type: String
    Description: Account ID of admin account (containing user to allow)
  Username:
    Type: String
    Description: Username to be allowed access
  BucketPrefix:
    Type: String
    Description: Bucket to be allowed (prefix appended with -{AccountId}-{Region})

Resources:
  CrossAccountRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Principal:
              AWS:
                - !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AccountId}:user/${Username}
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: skynet-s3-delegate
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - s3:ListBucket
                  - s3:GetObject
                Resource: "*"
```

But I find that I still get an error when I try to assume the role:

> `aws s3 cp skynet-lambda.zip s3://skynet-lambda-TARGET_ACCOUNT_ID-ap-southeast-1 --profile skynetci-cross-account`
>
> `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam::MAIN_ACCOUNT_ID:user/circleci-skynet is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::TARGET_ACCOUNT_ID:role/StackSet-df0e85b0-d6fd-47bf-a0bb-CrossAccountRole-1EW45TXEFAY0D`

Why is this so considering I already have the following policy for the user

```
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "sts:AssumeRole"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::TARGET_ACCOUNT_ID:role/StackSet-df0e85b0-d6fd-47bf-a0bb-CrossAccountRole-1EW45TXEFAY0D"
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have Bucket Policy update to allow cross account access a sample policy would be like:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Sid": "Example permissions",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountB-ID:root"
         },
         "Action": [
            "s3:*"
         ],
         "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Also make sure IAM user who is trying to access has this inline policy attached:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Sid": "Example",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
            "s3:*"
         ],
         "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

You can refer [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html#cross-acct-access-step0)

Answer (score 1):

I am attaching a working example that I tested using two of my accounts.

STEP 1: CloudFormation YAML template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion : '2010-09-09'
Description: 'Skynet stack to allow admin account deploying user to access S3'

Parameters:
  AccountId:
    Type: String
    Description: Account ID of admin account (containing user to allow)
  Username:
    Type: String
    Description: Username to be allowed access
  BucketPrefix:
    Type: String
    Description: Bucket to be allowed (prefix appended with -{AccountId}-{Region})

Resources:
  CrossAccountRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Principal:
              AWS:
                - !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AccountId}:user/${Username}
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: skynet-s3-delegate
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - s3:ListBucket
                  - s3:GetObject
                Resource: "*"
  RootInstanceProfile: 
    Type: "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile"
    Properties: 
      Path: "/"
      Roles: 
          - 
            Ref: "CrossAccountRole"
```

STEP 2: Create the cross account profile

Modify ~/.aws/credentials. Add a new profile called "skynetci-cross-account". Modify based upon your parameters created in STEP 1. You will need the role arn to replace the one below. You will also need the profile name for the account that you are giving permission to. In this example the profile name is "default".

Example here:

```
[skynetci-cross-account]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::191070ABCDEF:role/Test-CrossAccountRole-IZDDLRUMABCD
source_profile = default
```

STEP 3: Test cross access

aws --profile skynetci-cross-account s3 ls s3://bucket-name

Comment: So the difference with original is the `InstanceProfile` part? I looked it up and its supposedly used with EC2 instances? Isit correct to use without EC2? Whats an instance profile actually? It sounds like just a role? 

How does it compare the the S3 bucket method?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I tested from my desktop. The S3 bucket method is just another way of accomplishing the same goal. Note: I took your cloudformation template and then corrected it as that is what your question asked for.

Comment: Thank you for this alternative method. Seems like most ppl I ask used the S3 bucket policy route. I think I'd use that instead. Its alittle more intuitive somehow. Like in this case, I dont really understand what the instance profile does

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish your goal, you need to set a bucket policy in your target S3 bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DelegateS3Access",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::MAIN_ACCOUNT_ID:USER_NAME"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And allow S3 permissions to this user.

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Sid": "Example",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
            "s3:*"
         ],
         "Resource": [
             "*"            
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

In this case you do not need assume a role on the target account. The user itself will be able to access to bucket in another account.